# Can't access object property even though console.log clearly shows an Object with the needed property (React Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Working with React, Redux and React-Redux.

Subscribed to the store correctly, but as soon as I try drilling into the Object I get a 'Cannot read property 'x' of undefined'. Any property in the Object is off-limits for some reason that escapes me.

See the code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class NavList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>hello</div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  // console.log(state.app.data);
    return {
      data: state.app.data
    };
  }

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NavList)
```

And screen capture:

[image: chrome debugger screen capture]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are fetching this data async. As such, when your component is initially rendered, it has not yet populated your redux application state.

That is why you are getting 'x' of undefined.

Few ways around this:

1. Have an initialState set in your reducer
2. Use a library (at my work we use [idx](https://github.com/facebookincubator/idx)) safely check whether a value / property exists
3. Manually check e.g. `state && state.app && state.app.data || []`

Comment: if this was the right answer @bazfer please mark it as answering your question.

Comment: Will do once I verify it.

Comment: Marked. Thank you again for your input, it launched me into a deeper exploration of Redux and the systems design behind it.

Comment: Great to hear!!